# How to get the stacklayout that contains a button when the button is clicked?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, stacklayout

Im using a stacklayout that contains some other elements and a button.

```
<StackLayout x:Name="layout">
   <Button Text="Button" Clicked="Action"/>
<StackLayout/>
```

Is there a way to get the StackLayout that contains the button when it is clicked?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have an array that contains some other stacks and I want to get the stacklayout to delete it when the button is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Parent property

```
void Action(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
     var button = sender as Button;
     var stackLayout = button.Parent as StackLayout;
     stackLayout.Children.Remove(button); 
}
```

Comment: Or you can just use `layout.Remove(button)`, if coding in your xaml.cs

Comment: yep providing that all buttons using this event handler are children of layout, but could be that the OP is using this same event handler for several buttons (even for those which are children of another StackLayout different than layout). from [the op comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67203734/how-to-get-the-stacklayout-that-contains-a-button-when-the-button-is-clicked/67203823?noredirect=1#comment118788362_67203734) "I have an array that contains some other stacks"